# Dynamically referencing a controller action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to display a dynamic list of links inside a page as follows:

```
<% locations = get_locations() %>

<ul>
  <% locations.each { |loc| %>
      <li><%= link_to loc['name'], show_location_path(:id => loc['id']) %></li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

This code goes a 500 server error.

I verified that loc['id'] and loc['name'] are valid, by doing:

```
<ul>
  <% locations.each { |loc| %>
      <li><%= loc['name'] %></li>
      <li><%= loc['id'] %></li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

This does not cause a 500 error, and the list if properly displayed. Any ideas?

## Answer:

In the view:

<%= link_to loc['name'], {:controller => 'location', :action => 'show', :id => loc['id']} %>

and in the controller:

params[:id]

Comment: IF you try <li><%= link_to loc['name'],:id => loc['id'] %></li>
What do you have?

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper Please share the server log generated when you get this error.

Comment: what are the routes you want to link to?

Comment: The error log only produced: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 526ms. Not very helpful

Comment: To: @macario: the route I want to link to is listed in my question: show_location_path

Comment: To Carlos Morales: I get the same error message: Completed 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper Lets discuss this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have routes defined as `resources :locations`.

Then, to create a link for **show** action, use this:

```
<ul>
  <% locations.each do |loc| %>
      <li><%= link_to loc['name'], location_path(loc['id']) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: people started writing *rails* not completing the tutorials.. I think.. :-) That's how such questions produced..

Comment: This actually does not work. It produces links in the following form: /location.1 instead of /location/1. Back to square 1

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if the syntax is right ,

```
show_location_path(:id => loc['id'])
```

Shouldn't it be?

```
show_location_path(loc['id'])
```

Comment: I should be able to pass a parameter. What if it wasn't id? how would I pass a parameter?